# Optimal decision with continuous, stochastic signals and rewards

Tags: markov-decision-process, data-science, exploration-strategies, decision-theory, optimal-policy

I am performing a task, where I have to decide which projects to pursue at a given point in time, where the projects have different horizons of 30 minutes.

At a given point in time, forecasts are made on the profit of project that terminates 1 halfhour out in time, 2 halfhour out in time and so on up to 6 periods out in time. This give a "signal" on the outcome of the various decision, where time can be allocated to the different projects with different horizons and the profit is determined by how much time is allocated i.e. price/timeunit * timeunit, where the forecast is specified in price/timeunit. As the profit is only "expectations" they are not known for sure but they will either be at least as good as the forecast, or 0, depending on how things evolve within the next 30 minutes. The profit depends on the forecast in reality because the forecast influence the realized price/timeunit, but there is also data on the "optimal price/timeunit" i.e. the largest values that would have been possible in a perfect foresight scenario.

After the next minutes occur, a forecast is then again made from this new state with the same horizons as before. The thing is that the choice of horizon in the previous state influence whether it is possible to take on additional projects in this state because only a certain amount of projects is allowed (specified in time consumption and is NOT an integer number of projects but fractional). It might be the case that projects with longer horizons have a higher profit when being in a current state, but they will also constrain the flexibility of taking on additional (and maybe more profitable) projects as time pass by because time consumption is too high already.

I want to come up with either a decision policy or a way to weight the expected profits at a given point in time, to see if it is ever profitable to take on projects with longer horizon, and how much larger the profit has to be when doing that.

I have data on the forecast of profit and also data on the realized profit when taking the various decisions based on the forecast. And also the perfect foresight profits. All of these can be any non-negative real value as it is not possible to lose money but only make bad decisions resulting in lost opportunity. As mentioned only a pre-specified total "time consumption" but I do not have data on that but I can make various assumptions that I can allocate percentage of the total available time consumptions on various project e.g. 60% on a given range and 40% on another with longer horizon.

The only way that I can come up with on performing this analysis is a Markov Decision Problem with different states and stochastic rewards and stochastic states following a given decision, but I think it is hard to specify the state space and decisions as they depend the forecast and accumulated time consumption, and I dont know whether it is possible to make such analysis without simplifying the signals/rewards by dividing them into groups and not letting the reward and signals be continuous values. Also the process never terminates in reality so I do not know how to cope with that. The overall target is to come up with a way to determine how the available time consumption at a given point in time should be allocated based on the forecast because the projects with a longer horizon sometimes will have larger profit but restrict the possibilities in later states. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

**Comment**
So to elaborate: I get forecasts on the profit of various projects but they are uncertain (if the forecast is to high it will lead to 0 profit, but if it is lower than the upper bound of market participation it will lead to a profit >= forecast), but the goal is to know how to use these forecasts for decision making i.e. which projects to engage in either fully or fractional split between the different projects (1 project pr. horizon). I have timeseries data on the forecasts and the realized profit for taking various decision at given points in time, and the decision at a given state will influence up to the 6 following states as I work with a forecast horizon of 1-6 halfhours and the states is determined by the forecasts happening every 30 minute.